# Edit UIDatePicker with button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, uidatepicker

In my app I have next and previous week buttons, but also a UIDatePicker. So lets say I press the net week button, how can I adjust the day in the UIDatePicker to increase by 7 days? And visa versa for back 7 days.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `dateByAddingTimeInterval:` method of the `NSDate` class, and the `setDate:animated:` method of the `UIDatePicker` class, to adjust the picker's current date:

```
NSDate *currentDate = [datePicker date];

// Set the date 7 days earlier
NSDate *sevenDaysEarlier = [currentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-(60 * 60 * 24 * 7)];
[datePicker setDate:sevenDaysEarlier animated:YES];

// Set the date 7 days later
NSDate *sevenDaysLater = [currentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60 * 60 * 24 * 7];
[datePicker setDate:sevenDaysLater animated:YES];
```